# Reducing Block Matrices to their Sum

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Is there an efficient way to reduce a block matrix to a sum of all of its values? I'm looking to calculate the Euclidean distance between two block matrices (d2, as defined in the response here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507742/distance-similarity-between-two-matrices).

As a follow up, there doesn't appear to be a simple way to subtract two block matrices. Is there any way to multiply each by a constant?

Edit: Found a workaround for subtraction. V, W, and H are the three matrices. The negOneBlock is a matrix of size V which only contain negative ones.

```
V.add((W.multiply(H)).multiply(negOneBlock))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying a sum for each block and then reducing should quite efficient.

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed._

def sum(mat: BlockMatrix) = mat.blocks.map(_._2.toArray.sum).sum
```

where

```
_.blocks
```

creates a `RDD[((Int, Int), Matrix)]`,

```
_._2
```

extracts `Matrix`, and

```
toArray.sum
```

aggregates all values in the block. For data like:

```
val mat: BlockMatrix = new CoordinateMatrix(sc.parallelize(Seq(
  MatrixEntry(0, 10, 1.0), MatrixEntry(10, 1024, 2.0),  
  MatrixEntry(3000, 10, 3.0))
)).toBlockMatrix(128, 128)

sum(mat)
```

we get expected result which 6.0.